# Windows dumps all files into root directory of OneDrive

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

Windows 8.1
I went to Desktop folder and clicked on Properties -Location then Move and moved the Desktop folder to OneDrive.  I did the same for the Pictures folder.

Then I noticed that all of a sudden my desktop in front of me was filled up with files and folders from my Pictures folder.  I looked in OneDrive and saw that I had apparently moved the -contents- of the Desktop and Pictures folders to OneDrive, but I didn't move them into a Desktop and Pictures folder but rather into the root of the OneDrive.

Now, whatever files I add into the Desktop or Pictures folders end up in the root directory of the OneDrive.  I can't move them back.  What can I do (or should I just give up and reinstall Windows 8 again (then go through the whole upgrade process)?  Yuck.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

- Re-point your Desktop to OneDrive\Desktop
- Re-point your Pictures to OneDrive\Pictures

You'll have to figure out which files belong to their respective folders *after* you perform the re-points.

[image]